# WS2813 LED data permanently latching on power-on

Tags: microcontroller, led, switch-mode-power-supply, ground, latch

I'm running into a problem where WS2813 LEDs 'latch' data permanently on start-up sometimes. The issue is sporadic, and random data is latched (RGB segments are enabled at random brightness levels on some LEDs). No signal can be sent over the data-line to clear the LEDs, but a power cycle usually will solve the issue, and turn off the LED, making it once again receptive to data from my microcontroller.

My design is a microcontroller controlling WS2813 LEDs over bit-banged GPIO, both powered from the same 5V switch-mode power supply that I've put together.

[image: SMPS]

The data from the microcontroller GPIO is 3.3v, so I convert it to 5V for the LEDs with a 74HCT245.

[image: 74HCT245]

I have 3 theories, but no current way to test their viability -

1. There's a potential spike in the voltage of the SMPS, which.. magically causes this effect.
2. The ground of my LEDs being star-connected to the ground of my microcontroller through an 0603 0R resistor is... magically causing the effect.
3. Maybe the microcontroller GPIO is in an open-drain state at start-up, the 74HCT245 does not know what to do and goes a bit haywire and the LEDs don't like being presented with that at start-up.

Has anybody run into this issue, or perhaps has a hunch as to what could be going on here?

Edit: I've attached the full schematic of my board design, for context[image]

Comment: Which microcontroller are you using? And what voltage are you running it on. No, wait I see, 3.3V

Comment: I'm using the STM32F334. I've added the full schematic in the original post

Comment: Great info. Seems like it could be glitchy power, take control of that /OE pin and make sure you have a proper power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the manual of your MCU. If your GPIOs during power-on are high-z, I would attach a pullup to /OE (pin 19) of the 74HCT245. You have to cut the existing trace to GNDA of course. Then add a GPIO to it so you can control when it's ready.

Also your L2, L4 looks like you have two inductors in series which could cause some undesired effects like noise on the output. You can do it like this but probably want to use shielded inductors to avoid coupling.

Edit: Clarified note on L2+L4.